# Ajax form in partial view validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form inside a partial view, it works but in case a server side validation error is raised it displays only the partial view. So I decided to use ajax for the submission (actually it makes sense as it is inserting a contact and there's a list in the main view).

Thing is, with the posted code if one of these errors comes it's properly displayed in the view (I'd need to make the partial visible again, but that's another thing), but if there's no error it'll display the list only in the partial view. I can do the other way round, displaying properly when there's no error but then not achieving the proper displaying of validation errors.

I would like to understand what's the best approach, or at least which are the possibilities: maybe change the code in the controller or do some kind of check in the success callback...

I edit what I had before, because when no error I should return the list, not the whole view as I posted before, but anyway I still have the doubt on how to tell one from another as both are succesfull calls to the post action

Thanks

The view is this one

```
@model ContactListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = " My Contacts"
}

<div id="ContactList">
    <h2>My Contacts</h2>
    <hr />
    <div id="addContainer">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("AddContact"); }
    </div>
    <div id="editContainer" data-amp-url="@Url.Action("Edit", "Contacts")" class="initiallyHidden"></div>
    @foreach (var group in Model.Contacts)
    {
        <div class="PlanContacts">
            <div class="PlanName">@group.Key</div>
            @foreach (var contact in group.Values)
            {
                <div class="Preview">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => contact, "Contact")
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

@section PageJavascript
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/AMPContacts.js"></script>
}
```

The controller post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddContact(AddContactViewModel viewModel)
{
    var partyId = (int) Session["PartyId"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _contactsManager.AddContact(viewModel, partyId);
        // Here I should return the updated list
    }
    var newViewModel = _createBuilder.Rebuild(viewModel, partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddContact", newViewModel);
}
```

And the ajax submission code inside the longer AMPContact.js

```
$('#addForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addContainer = $(document.getElementById('addContainer'));
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            addContainer.html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've got to this http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/handling-validation-errors-on-ajax.html looks interesting, I'm gonna try this approach

Answer (score 0):

I understand this answer it's far from being good but maybe it's useful for somebody in terms of narrowing a possible search. As it would ended up being huge I rather post this update as an answer to my own question, not sure if it complies with good manners.

The explained one wasn't the only problem I faced, hard times as well with the reset of the form and specially the successive error submissions (once I got an error trying to submit it with errors again), so I ended up making a mess out of different solutions for different problems. Hopefully I will be able to clean it up

Thanks

In the view I use now

```
<div id="myContacts">
<h2>My Contacts</h2>
<hr />

<div id="addContainer">
    <div class="toggler">
        Add Contact
    </div>
    <div id="addToggling" class="initiallyHidden">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("AddContact"); }
    </div>
</div>

<div id="editContainer" data-amp-url="@Url.Action("Edit", "Contacts")" class="initiallyHidden"></div>

<div id="list">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ContactList", Model); }
</div>
```

In the .js

```
$('#addContainer').on('submit', '#addForm', ajaxCall);

function ajaxCall(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addToggling = $(document.getElementById('addToggling'));
    var contactList = $(document.getElementById('contactList'));

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.passedValidation == true) {
                // Json is returned with flag, we get the list from the server and update the list element
                $.get(result.action, function (partial) {
                    contactList.html(partial);
                });

                // Add some effects and clear the form
                $(document).scrollTop(0);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    addToggling.slideUp(300, resetAddForm);
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    contactList.effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
                }, 1000);
            }
            else {
                // The form partial view is returned and displayed in the same element when there are validation errors
                $(document).scrollTop(0);
                addToggling.html(result);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addForm');
            }
        }
    });
}

function resetAddForm() {
    var addForm = $(document.getElementById('addForm'));

    // Hhide the error messages
    addForm.find("span.field-validation-error").hide();
    addForm.find("div.validation-summary-errors").hide();

    // Removes the class associated to errors
    addForm[0].reset();

    // Clear the inputs
    addForm.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    addForm.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

Controller with the existing action method slightly changed and a new one

```
public ActionResult ContactList()
{
    var partyId = (int)Session["PartyId"];
    var viewModel = _displayBuilder.Build(partyId);
    return PartialView("_ContactList", viewModel);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddContact()
{
    var partyId = (int) Session["PartyId"];
    var viewModel = _createBuilder.Build(partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddContact", viewModel);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddContact(AddContactViewModel viewModel)
{
    var partyId = (int) Session["PartyId"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _contactsManager.AddContact(viewModel, partyId);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new { passedValidation = true, action = Url.Action("ContactList")});

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var newViewModel = _createBuilder.Rebuild(viewModel, partyId);
    return PartialView("_AddContact", newViewModel);
}
```